# Ionic storage Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Whenever I am using storage I am getting back `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` But it seems to work on some devices so it works on an android 6.0.1 but does not work on android 5.1.1

```
doRoles(): any{
    this.storage.get('role_id').then(
      (role_id) => {
        console.log('test');
        this.menu.enable(role_id == 1, 'guardianMenu');
        this.menu.enable(role_id == 2, 'schoolMenu');
        this.menu.enable(role_id == 3, 'faithLeaderMenu');
        this.menu.enable(role_id == 4, 'layMinisterMenu');
        if (role_id == '4' || role_id == '3'){
          this.nav.setRoot('EventsPage');
        }
        if (role_id == '2'){
          this.nav.setRoot('SchoolPage');
        }
        if (role_id == '1'){
          this.nav.setRoot('GuardianPage');
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: How can it work if you have a typescript syntax error?

Comment: @PhilipBrack I found out that it is because something is missing in android 5.1.1 but is included int 6.0.1 But i cannot remember what is was. I think it was something to do with promises.